# How can i check the connection off/on using ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework

with what i can replace " Network.connection"? it's no more valid !! please i need help

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
isOnline(): boolean {
 if(this.onDevice && Network){
 return Network.connection!== Connection.NONE;
} else {
  return navigator.onLine; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for the plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/

But in your case it seems to work with

```
return this.network.type != 'none';
```

After injecting the plugin of course.